# How to execute a command when player joins world MC Forge 1.18.2?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I am trying to make a message be sent out in chat when a player joins a world in MC 1.18.2 Forge that is clickable (it will link to an issues page on github), but I can't figure out how to make the tellraw command be executed when it is clicked. All tutorials on ClickEvents are outdated, so I can't use any of them. Thanks in advance.

Command: `/tellraw @s {"text":"PLACEHOLDER","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"https://www.google.com/search?q=PLACEHOLDER"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","contents":["PLACEHOLDER"]}}`

My Current Code:

```
static int messageAlreadyReceived = 0;
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void onEntityJoinWorld(@NotNull EntityJoinWorldEvent event) {
        if(event.getEntity() != null && event.getEntity() instanceof Player) {
            if(messageAlreadyReceived == 0) {
                messageAlreadyReceived = 1;
                Entity player = event.getEntity();
                String testVariable = "CLICK ME";
                String testVariable2 = "CLICK ME 2";

                TextComponent tC = new TextComponent(testVariable);
                TextComponent tC2 = new TextComponent(testVariable2);
                TextComponent tC3 = new TextComponent(testVariable);

                tC.getStyle().withClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, "/kill @a"));
                player.sendMessage(tC, player.getUUID());
                tC2.getStyle().withClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, "kill @a"));
                player.sendMessage(tC2, player.getUUID());

                ClickEvent cE1 = new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, "/kill @a");

                player.sendMessage(tC3.setStyle(Style.EMPTY.withClickEvent(cE1)), player.getUUID());

                ClickEvent cE2 = new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, "kill @a");

                player.sendMessage(tC3.setStyle(Style.EMPTY.withClickEvent(cE2)), player.getUUID());
            } else {
                messageAlreadyReceived = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Java: 17.0.2
Minecraft: Forge 1.18.2-40.0.5

Comment: Are you making use of a modified server environment at all? This would classically be a server-sided addition, and your client would need to send that info to every player when they connect. This is okay for small worlds (e.g. hosted within your client), but I suppose that's an aside at this point.

Comment: This message is meant for single player worlds, not multiplayer.

Comment: You should be able to simply `EntityPlayer#sendMessage`, but rather than using a command, you'd want a `ClickEvent` for `ClickEvent.Action.OPEN_URL`. Note that the text components can be appended to each other (`TextComponent#append`), such that you would simply make the part that was only the link be an `OPEN_URL` component (with the text/style you want), and then appending that link to the first part of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer moved from body of question:

> I figured out the answer by having the send message code look like this: `player.sendMessage(tC.plainCopy().withStyle(Style.EMPTY.withClickEvent(cE1)), player.getUUID());`